# Find $P \left(X<\frac{2}{3}|Y=\frac{1}{3} \right)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is $f(x,y)=3y$ for $0\le x\le y\le 1$ and 0 for otherwise. Find $$P \left(X<\frac{2}{3}\Bigg| Y=\frac{1}{3} \right)$$

---

I am confused about this one since
$$
P \left(X<\frac{2}{3}\Bigg|Y=\frac{1}{3} \right)=\frac{P \left(X<\frac{2}{3},Y=\frac{1}{3} \right)}{P \left(Y=\frac{1}{3} \right)}
$$

I can get the marginal of $Y$:
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{0}^y f(x,y) \, dx=3y^2, 0\le y\le 1.
$$

So $P \left(Y=\frac{1}{3} \right)=1/3$. But what is $P \left(X<\frac{2}{3},Y=\frac{1}{3} \right)$? Is it
$$
P \left(X<\frac{2}{3},Y=\frac{1}{3} \right)=\int\int_D f(x,y)\,dx \,dy
$$
where $D= \left\{ \left\{X<\frac{2}{3},Y=\frac{1}{3} \right\} \right \}\cap \{0\le x\le y\le 1\}\}$

Comment: That's the correct $D$

Comment: If $0 \leq X \leq Y \leq 1$, then when $Y=1/3$, $X$ must be less than or equal to $1/3$.  So the probability of $X<2/3$ given $Y=1/3$ is $1$.

Comment: $Y=1/3$ is a zero probability event because $Y$ is continuous. You need to find the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. To find $P(X<\frac{2}{3}|Y=\frac{1}{3})$, you first need to compute the joint probability $P(X<\frac{2}{3},Y=\frac{1}{3})$ using the joint probability density function:
\begin{align*}
P(X<\frac{2}{3},Y=\frac{1}{3}) &= \iint_D f(x,y) , dxdy \\
&= \int_{1/3}^{2/3} \int_{0}^{2/3} 3y , dx , dy \\
&= \frac{1}{3},
\end{align*}

where $D$ is the region of integration given by $D = {(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3} \leq y \leq 1}$.

Then, using the formula $P(X<\frac{2}{3}|Y=\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{P(X<\frac{2}{3},Y=\frac{1}{3})}{P(Y=\frac{1}{3})}$, we get:
$$
P(X<\frac{2}{3},Y=\frac{1}{3}) = \int_{1/3}^{2/3} \int_{x}^{1/3} 3y \, dy \, dx = \frac{1}{18}.
$$

Comment: Your integration limits are not consistent with $0\leq x \leq y \leq 1$.

Comment: The marginal pdf for $Y$ is $3y^2$ for $0\leq y \leq 1$ and zero otherwise.  That makes the density of $X|Y=y$ as $1/y$ for $0\leq x \leq y \leq 1$ and zero otherwise.  In other words, $X|Y=y$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,y]$.  As noted by @stubbornatom $P(X<2/3, Y=1/3) = 0.

Comment: @JimB Note that $X|Y=y=1/y$. So $P(X<2/2|Y=1/3)=3$?

Comment: @Hermi You both are confusing "probability" with "probability density".

Comment: @JimB Sorry... So $P(X<2/3|Y=1/3)=\int_0^{2/3} f_{X|Y}(x|y=1/3)dx=\int_0^{2/3} 3 dx=2$? But it is still impossible? Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Hermi: $\int_0^{2/3}f_{X|Y}(x|y=1/3)dx=\int_0^{1/3}3~ dx+ \int_{1/3}^{2/3} 0~ dx=1+0=1$.